# Doesn't .setDataArray method accept date type?

Tags: arrays, basic, jagged-arrays, openoffice-basic

The code below, which should creates a jagged array, so that I could then paste its content to the sheet, by using the .setDataArray method, do not work.

I got the error: "BASIC runtime error. Object variable not set."

But it seems, by making some tests, that I actually have a jagged array with 9 "rows" and an one-dimensional array as each of its elements.

```
sub build_jagged_array()

    dim my_date as date, num_rows as long, arr1(), arr2
    my_date = dateserial(1994,7,1)
    num_rows = 9
    redim arr1(0 to num_rows-1)
    for i = 0 to num_rows-1
        arr2 = array(dateadd("m",i,my_date))
        arr1(i) = arr2
    next i

    sheet = thiscomponent.getsheets.getbyname("main")
    range_saida = sheet.getCellRangeByName("A20:A28")
    'with the arr1 below, the setDataArray method works     
    'arr1 = array(array(1),array(1),array(1),array(1),array(1),array(1),array(1),array(1),array(1))
    range_saida.setdataarray(arr1)

end sub
```

while doing my tests, I changed arr1, created by the sub above, for the following arr1, and the .setDataArray worked as expected:

```
arr1 = array(array(1),array(1),array(1),array(1),array(1),array(1),array(1),array(1),array(1))
```

Please, what is wrong with the sub above?

Answer (score 0):

I aparentlly found the problem. `.setDataArray` method it seems it do not allow the array content be of the date type. So I changed the line:

```
arr2 = array(dateadd("m",i,my_date))
```

for the line

```
arr2 = array(dateadd(clng("m",i,my_date)))
```

Now the code works as expected, except that I have to format the cell as date type so it do not shows an integer number instead of a date.